# Slicing generator object from Twitter API

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, twitter

I'm using Twython to search Twitter for tweets about the Superbowl.

I got the API to work -- it returns a huge bulk of tweets and their metadata in a generator objects called `results`:

```
results = twitter.cursor(twitter.search, q='superbowl', lang = 'en', result_type = 'popular')
```

I can print off all the contents using:

```
for result in results: 
    print(result)
```

The trouble is actually getting this all into a dictionary or some kind of data structure (perhaps even Panda dataframe would be ideal, with a row per tweet) I can later subset for analysis. When I run the following code:

```
for result in results:
    d = dict(result)
```

`d` is a dictionary for *one* of the tweets. So, not terribly helpful since I want to access all the tweets in `results`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe have a list of dicts? `results_list = map(dict, results)`.

Comment: You should first declare d as a dictionary e.g. `d=dict()`, then, if you wanna loop through results, you'd assign values like `d['key']=value`

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov The problem is I don't know how many entries are in the generator object ... so, assigning keys is tough?

Comment: Can you post what `results` is and what you're trying to achieve? Is `results` list, dictionary, or json?